# where is schemagentask in new jaxb implementation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to use the the class 'com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenTask' to generate xsd from java. However, when I tried to download the glassfish version or the sun-version of the library jaxb-xjc (version number 2.11/2.12) I could not find the class. Is the class moved? Should I use a different library? I have moved back to an older version of jaxb-xjc where I can find it (2.2.7).

Comment: Using java.lang.Process and ProcessBuilder might be simple enough if you really need to invoke schemagen from a Java application.

Comment: I am trying to do this from a gradle build script. I have been following this setup: https://joerglenhard.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/xjc-and-schemagen-with-gradle/ but wanted to see if it would be possible to update the library versions

Answer (score 0):

It's now in the library `jaxb-jxc`, under the same group ID `com.sun.xml.bind`. Its documentation is [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-jxc/3.0.1/com.sun.tools.jxc/com/sun/tools/jxc/SchemaGenTask.html).